# Rails 4: around_action with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In order to drastically reduce code repetition, I want to write up a concern with a generic way to add a special `around_action` to a controller. It is basically supposed to catch any exception, render the right template and add the exception as a notice. However, it must be applicable to different actions, and show different templates depending on the action. My goal is basically to be able to do this:

```
protect_from_exception_with 'index', only: [ :update ]
```

In order to achieve this, I tried to write up my concern like this (Using Rails 4.1):

```
module CatchException
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def protect_from_exception_with(failure_template, params)
      around_action -> { catch_exception_with(failure_template) }, params
    end
  end

  private

  def log_error(e)
    # Many things happen here
  end

  def catch_exception_with(failure_template)
    yield
  rescue => e
    log_error(e)
    render failure_template
  end
end
```

However, this leads to an error:

```
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
```

I have trying to find examples for `around_action` or `around_filter` with a parameter, but could only find them for `before_action`.

I hope what I'm trying to achieve is at all possible, otherwise I'd need to write a new method in every controller for every action I need to achieve this.

Comment: `catch_exception_with` needs to take a block, and you need to pass a block into `around_action` too.

Comment: @fylooi I figures as much but I could not figure out how to do that. I'm not really a ruby wizard.

Comment: Funnily enough, it seems to be working for me with `protect_from_exception_with(:edit, only: :show)`

Comment: You can call `around_action` with both params and lambda, but you'll need to switch the parameter order and convert the lambda into a block. `around_action params, &(-> { catch_exception_with(failure_template) })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some clues:

1. [around_action](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-around_action) receives a `callback` and a `block` as params, if we send a `function` as the 1st param, that `function` mustn't have any parameter!
2. We can send a block instead (like you did) but we must pass the current given block to that block as well, your code misses the passing block, that is why the exception raised.
3. In `protect_from_exception_with`, I can call `block_given?`, it returns `true`, but I don't know how to get the block out!

This works:

```
module CatchException
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def protect_from_exception_with(failure_template, params)
      around_action -> { catch_exception_with(failure_template) }, params
    end
  end

  private

  def log_error(e)
    # Many things happen here
  end

  def catch_exception_with(failure_template)
    self.send(params[:action])
  rescue => e
    log_error(e)
    render failure_template
  end
end
```

Thankfully, we still have the params in `catch_exception_with`, make it easy, call the action back to the controller!

Comment: This will not work when I use `protect_from_exception_with` more than once in the controller, unfortunately.

Comment: @LambdaDusk: This is interesting! I updated some clues, and still finding a better solution :)

Comment: @LambdaDusk: Check new updated solution out, now it is much better!